# Callable Cloud Functions Returning Null in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, flutter-web

> ## My Goal:
>
> I wish to call a **Cloud Function** in my ***Flutter App*** which retrieves a ***JSON obj*** from a ***Python-FastAPI server*** and displays content in ***Alert Dialogue***.

> ## The Error:
>
> The Callable Function Service within my flutter app recieves null. My alert dialog displays "Null Value Error" as triggered by my code.

[image: Error Message]

## Cloud Side Operations:

#### My Cloud Function works in 2 parts:

> - Receive data from client (Flutter APP) in **Callable Http Function**
> - Call Python API => return to Cloud Function which returns to Client

**Cloud Function:**

```
exports.getRandomPassword = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const useSymbols = data.useSymbols;
  const pwLength= data.pwLength;

  const debug ={
    received_data_type: typeof data,
    received_data:data,
    pwLen_type: typeof pwLength,
    pwLength,
    useSymbols_type:typeof useSymbols,
    useSymbols,
  }

  console.log(debug);
  await callAPI(pwLength,useSymbols).then((res:any) =>{
    console.log(`Resulting Payload: ${res}`);
    return res});

});
```

**Python-FastAPI Call:**

```
async function callAPI(pwLength: any, useSymbols: any) {
  // BUILD URL STRING WITH PARAMS
  const ROOT_URL = `http://[IP_Address]/password?pwd_length=${pwLength}&use_symbols=${useSymbols}`;
  let res;
  // let password: any; // password to be received

  await http.get(ROOT_URL)
    .then((response: any) => {
      console.log("TO APP "+JSON.stringify(response));
      console.log(response.getBody());
      res = response.getBody() as Map<any, any>;

    })
    .catch((err: any) => {
      console.log(err);
      res= err;
    });

  return res;
}
```

**The resulting payload works correctly as seen in my Logs:**

[image: Cloud Function Logs]

## Client Side Operations:

**On Button Click in Flutter:**

```
                        onPressed: () async {
                          // call cloud function & use set state to store pw
                          await getPassword().then((String result) {
                            setState(() {
                              password = result;
                            });
                          });
                          showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) => DisplayPassword());
                        },
```

**My Flutter getPassword() Function:**

```
Future<String> getPassword() async {
  var pw;
  final HttpsCallable callable = new CloudFunctions()
      .getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'getRandomPassword')
        ..timeout = const Duration(seconds: 30);

  try {
    await callable.call(
      <String, dynamic>{
        'pwLength': 10,
        'useSymbols': true,
      },
    ).then((value) {
      print(value.data);
      print(value.data.runtimeType);
      pw = value.data;
      return pw;
    });
  } on CloudFunctionsException catch (e) {
    print('caught firebase functions exception');
    print('Code: ${e.code}\nmessage: ${e.message}\ndetails: ${e.details}');

    return '${e.details}';
  } catch (e) {
    print('caught generic exception');
    print(e);
    return 'caught generic exception\n$e';
  }
}
```

**My Display Password Function:**

```
class DisplayPassword extends StatelessWidget {
  final String pw = (_MyPasswordGenPageState().password == null)
      ? 'null value error'
      : _MyPasswordGenPageState().password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text(pw),
    );
  }
}
```

> ***NOTE****
> I would like to keep the password retrieval as a Cloud Function, so it can be used on web-apps as well as mobile. I am however open to refactoring the entire operation if a better solution presents itself.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it due to the length of the post, but what is the problem? What is not working?

Comment: As the title suggests, the Cloud Function is returning null. I will update the question to better explain this.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but sometimes it received data, sometimes it considered it doesn't have any data or it is null value. Very weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### Solution:
>
> - Use Constructors for stateless widgets
> - avoid `.then()`
> - Cloud Functions should return `Promise.resolve()` when called in `async` function.

**On Button Click:**

```
    dynamic result =
        await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
      'pwLength': 10,
      'useSymbols': true,
      //await the result before continuing
    });

    setState(() {
      // convert hashmap to list and get first val
      password = result.data.values.toList()[0];
      isLoading = false; // remove loading indicator
    });


  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) =>
          DisplayPassword(password));
```

> For ease of reading I removed exception handling in the code above

**Displaying the Alert Dialog:**

```
    class DisplayPassword extends StatelessWidget {
      var password; // check if null
      DisplayPassword(this.password); // constructor
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // make sure null value isn't being passed to alert dialog widget
        if (password == null) {
          password = 'null value error';
        }
    
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(password),
        );
      }
    }
```

**Cloud Function:**

```
exports.getRandomPassword = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const useSymbols = data.useSymbols;
  const pwLength= data.pwLength;
  let password;
  password = await callAPI(pwLength,useSymbols);

  const debug ={
    received_data_type: typeof data,
    received_data:data,
    pwLen_type: typeof pwLength,
    pwLength,
    useSymbols_type:typeof useSymbols,
    useSymbols,
    ResultingPayloadType: typeof password,
    ResultingPayload: password,

  }

  console.log(debug);

  return Promise.resolve(password)

});


async function callAPI(pwLength: any, useSymbols: any) {
  // BUILD URL STRING WITH PARAMS
  const ROOT_URL = `http://[My_Api_IP_Address]/password?pwd_length=${pwLength}&use_symbols=${useSymbols}`;

  const res = await http.get(ROOT_URL);
  console.log(res.getBody());
  return res.getBody() as Map<String , any>;

}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work at all.

Comment: This solution was posted in 2020. A lot has changed with the firebase SDK and flutter since then. I cant verify if the solution still works or not but you can always see the latest flutter fire docs for functions here: https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_functions